# Orchard - link to a view/action in another module?

Tags: orchardcms

Say I am on Module1 -> Controller1 -> View1.

In View1, I want to add a regular hyperlink to Module2 -> Controller2 -> View2.

How do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ASP.NET MVC links point to **action on a controller**, not to a view. View can (but not have to be) returned from a given action as a result.

So, if your **View2** is returned from eg. action **MyAction** on **Controller2** sitting in **Module2**, then you can easily add a link to that action from anywhere by writing:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", 
                 "MyAction", 
                 "Controller2", 
                 new { area = "Module2" }, 
                 new {})
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", 
                 "MyAction", 
                 new { controller = "Controller2", area = "Module2" })
```

whichever looks better for you. There are a couple of other possible [overrides](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492936.aspx).

The *Area* route property is used in Orchard to specify the target module name.

Comment: Yes, I should have said action, not view (I keep using those terms interchangeably).    

But I tried these two, the link is not pointing to the right action.

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Action2", "Controller2", new {area = "Module2"})                                            
<a href="/OrchardLocal/Module2/Controller2/Controller2>Action2</a>

Comment: @Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "Action2", "Controller2", new {area = "Module2"})  
<a href="/OrchardLocal/Action2" area="Module2">Click Me</a>

Comment: Oh, sorry - entered incorrect parameters (`Url.Action` has *string, string, object* override, but the `Html.ActionLink` doesn't). Updated the answer accordingly.